# JSON.NET deserialize to list of runtime type

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

Have the dynamic type:

```
Type targetType;
if (position.Length == 1)
{
    targetType = typeof (Row);
}

if (position.Length == 4)
{
    targetType = typeof (Field);
}
```

After this I need to deserialize the JSON to List of this type:

```
List<targetType>
```

Code:

```
var components = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<targetType>>(include.components.ToString());
```

How I cat do this?

Comment: Not enough info.  JSON nowhere.

Comment: Can you put an example of the JSON that you want to parse?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String, Type)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) along with [`Type.MakeGenericType(Type[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var components = (IList)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(include.components.ToString(), typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { targetType }));
```

Incidentally, if `include.components` is a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm), it will be more efficient to use [`JToken.ToObject(Type)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject.htm):

```
var components = (IList)include.components.ToObject(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { targetType }));
```